# Elementor header breaks when custom css is used

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a header I am building in Elementor, and the buttons need to have custom CSS applied. For some  reason when I build the buttons that way, it causes the header to break and go to the next line. I've tried everything I can, including coding the entire header in Dreamweaver and then inserting it as a single html box, but it still does the same thing. I've written out the code for the buttons below, there are 5 of these plus a logo but if I add more than two of these types of buttons the problem occurs.

```
 <div class="svg-wrapper" style="white-space:nowrap;">
   <div align="centere">
  <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
    <div id="text">
        <p>
      <a href=""><span class="spot"></span>EXPERIENCES</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </svg>
</div>
```

```
<style>


.svg-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;

}

#shape {
  stroke-width: 6px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #fb9715;
  stroke-dasharray: 85 400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -220;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}

#text {
  margin-top: -42px;
  text-align: center;
}



.svg-wrapper:hover #shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 50 0;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke: #fb9715;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do ypu close `<div class="svg-wrapper"...>` properly? Because in your code a `</div>` is missing.

Comment: Good catch, but I fixed that and the problem is persisting. I'm like 99% sure this is an Elementor problem, I just don't know how to fix it aside from using a second builder Plugin.

Comment: I can put it into the header with the HTML Widget of Elementor Pro. When I use the Wordpress HTML widget, it doesn't work ... it looks kind of cool: http://test.flextensions.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to check the code using inspect tool??? some times elementor adds extra code.

Comment: I checked the inspect element, it looked like there were some superfluous Div tags that were generated by Elementor, which I'm guessing is the problem, but I'm not sure what I would be able to do about that without going outside of Elementor altogether.

Comment: there should be a class. choose the class and add style display none. this should solve it